# What is this wetland plant with small white flowers in a spiral around the stalk?

Tags: identification

This is a plant we found for the first time today. We live near an area that contains a vernal pool and frequently floods but never drains out. In 10 years, I've never seen this plant before.

Can anyone help identify it?

[image]

Comment: can you provide a picture of the leaf? It looks familiar...

Answer (score 5):

It's a [lady's tresses orchid (*Spiranthes*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiranthes) of some sort. Perhaps [*S. ovalis*](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/woodland/plants/ls_ladytress.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Spiranthes ochroleuca , yellow ladies'-tresses

Comment: Hi, can you give us more information on how you identified this plant?