# What kind of a plant is this (flowers in spiral)?

Tags: identification

[image]

It grows wild (Croatia), it's around 15 cm tall, tiny flowers grow in a spiral around the stem.

It seems to have a bulb root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search on the terms "white flowers in a spiral" produced a quick list containing [this previous question on this forum](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8448/what-is-this-wetland-plant-with-small-white-flowers-in-a-spiral-around-the-stalk) indicating Lady's Tresses Orchid ([Spiranthes ochroleuca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiranthes_ochroleuca)). The bulb root is consistent with an orchid if growing in a wetland, although in Croatia it is more likely to be [Spiranthes spiralis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiranthes_spiralis). S. spiralis has a green spot on the lower lip.

Comment: Thank you! I usually successfully identify local plants but this time I only got moor and fern results (I entered "plant spiral tiny flowers") I guess I should have been a bit more persistent :)